# About Delphi Wings (ORM)

Tags: delphi, orm

Someone knows if Delphi Wings (The Embarcadero ORM for Delphi) will be available in Delphi 2010? I'm testing some ORMs but I will preffer the Embarcadero one, if it's available shortly.

Regards,
Francis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wings isn't an officially endorsed Embarcadero ORM that will be part of Delphi.  It is a project developed by Paweł Głowacki, who is an Embarcadero employee.

Comment: Seems that Wings is stalled, isn'it?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know that Embarcadero plan something like this. CodeGear and current Delphi already supports [ECO](http://www.capableobjects.com/). See also [embarcadero developer network](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33020).
BTS ECO is an excellent framework that should be investigated, I have started using it myself.

Comment: ECO is for .NET while Delphi Wings is / will be for Win32.